# The interface jframe does not connect to sql

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, eclipse-neon

I can't connect to sql when I call this jframe from an other jframe.

I'm trying to open a jframe later the login screen, but when I call it from the login jframe the interface jframe doesn't connect to sql.

[image: img]

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                usu.setNome(txtusuario.getText());
                usu.setSenha(txtsenha.getText());
                if (usu.logar(usu.getNome(), usu.getSenha())) {

                    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                I_Adm frame = new I_Adm();
                                frame.setVisible(true);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    panel.setVisible(false);
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
```

Comment: "*java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.postgresql.Driver" --> you have not added the Postgres JDBC driver to your project

Answer (score 0):

Database connection has nothing to do with Swing, the problem you have is with that your database is out of reach because your application can't localize the database driver.

Did you put your driver's library into your classpath?

Comment: yes i put coiuld be some problem becuase the login is not indexed to this driver? both are in the same package